# Correlated factors in cfa

Tags: correlation, confirmatory-factor

I am a running a confirmatory factor analysis in r using the package lavaan. I am trying to measure a latent variable (e.g. time spent in exercise) in young adults and have 2 subjective measures and 3 objective measures of past exercise. None of these variables measure the exercise perfectly, therefore I am trying to use cfa to identify the latent variable "past time spent in exercise" from these 5 indicator variables.

The models suggest that these variables are best explained by two factors, one related to past exercise and one to more recent exercise like so

past exercise =~ subjective var1 + objective var1 + objective var2

recent exercise =~ subjective var1 + objective var2 + objective var3

The model fit statistics are fine (CFA>0.95, RMSEA <0.05). The subjective variables have the highest loading (0.6-0.8) while the objective measures have lower loading (0.2-0.4) but I have good reason to believe these measure exercise and should remain included. The correlation between the subjective measures is 0.26

When I generate factor scores from the above model, there is a high correlation between the two factors (r=0.73). I do expect the factors to be correlated but not this highly.
To look further into it, I separated the model into two, one for past exercise and one for recent exercise, and generated factor scores. The correlation between these two is milder (r=0.34).

My question is why are the two factors so much more highly correlated in the single model compared to the separate models? Is there ever justification for splitting one model into two?

P.S I do appreciate factor scores are indeterminate and thus not the best measure of the actual correlation between the factors.

Comment: What is the correlation between the factors in the model?

Comment: From the lavaan output, the estimate of the covariance between the two factors is: Estimate=0.034, Std.lv=0.513, Std.all=0.513. Is that what you're after?

Comment: I should also mention that there is missing data in ~1/3 of the sample of 300 people. I am using FIML. The data is missing at random as far as I can determine.

Comment: Yes. 0.53 is the result for your model. 0.73 is a touch higher, but not much. If you constrain the correlation to zero, I think you'll get the same result as separate models (I've never done that, so I might be wrong though).